# Cannot get table data with Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, scrapy

This is the website and I want to scrape the table data that correspond to `Category` and `SubCategory`.

https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US

[image]

I use Scrapy and Selenium to scrape. This is my code:

Import some libraries:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Main code:

```
class AdbcSpiderSelenium(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'adbc_selenium'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US']

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        chrome_path = 'D:\\work\\crawl data\\selenium_project\\chromedriver.exe'

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://www.adbc.gov.ae/BusinessActivityInfo/BusinessActivity.aspx?culture=en-US")

        tab = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlNatureId"))

        tab.select_by_value('ADVOCATE OFFICES')

        tab = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ddlSubCategId"))

        tab.select_by_value('Advertising Agent')

        self.html = driver.page_source

        driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        contents = resp.xpath('//*[@id="gvActivities"]/table//tr')
        for content in contents:
            yield {
                'code': content.xpath('td[1]//text()').get(),
                'name': content.xpath('td[2]//text()').get()
            }
```

What my code is trying to scrape the table data where `Business Category = ADVOCATE OFFICES` and `Business SubCategory = Advertising Agent` just the image above.

The code can run but it doesn't return any data of the table. What wrong with my code?

Comment: Seems like your xpath is incorrect `//table[@id="gvActivities"]//tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct xpath to use:
`//table[@id="gvActivities"]//tr`